# Django: Check which related object exists

Tags: python, django

I have two different models that reference the django `User`, namely `Recruiter` and `Userprofile`.

I have a function that receives a `User` object as an argument. I need to check which of the related objects exist and take some action accordingly. I am using nested try-catch for doing this:

```
def some_function(user, ....):
    ...
    try:
        profile = user.userprofile
        profile.profile_pic.save('{0}_social.jpg'.format(user.username))
        profile.save()
    except:
        try:
            recruiter = user.recruiter
            recruiter.cover_pic.save('{0}_social.jpg'.format(user.username))
            recruiter.save()
        except:
            pass
```

Is there a better/more elgant way of doing this?

**EDIT**: The models in consideration are as follows

```
class Recruiter(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, unique=True, related_name='recruiter')
    ...

class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, unique=True, related_name='userprofile')
    ...
```

Comment: Can you show the Recruiter and Userprofile model?

Comment: @Joseph: I've updated the question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the .exists() QuerySet API, like so (presuming `user` is an instance of the User model, and both Userprofile and Recruiter key to that model with a field also named `user`):

```
def some_function(user, ...):
    if Userprofile.objects.filter(user=user).exists()
        profile = user.userprofile
        profile.profile_pic.save('{0}_social.jpg'.format(user.username))
        profile.save()
    elif Recruiter.objects.filter(user=user).exists()
        recruiter = user.recruiter
        recruiter.cover_pic.save('{0}_social.jpg'.format(user.username))
        recruiter.save()
    else:
        # User has neither Userprofile nor Recruiter associated with it!
        # Do something here to handle that case, or just get rid of the else
```

Note that the `.exists()` call will first do a query to see if the object exists, and then the line that access that object (e.g, `user.userprofile`) will run another query to actually access that object.  A slightly optimized way, though maybe less readable, might be:

```
def some_function(user, ...):
    userprofiles = Userprofile.objects.filter(user=user)
    recruiters = Recruiter.objects.filter(user=user)
    if len(userprofiles):
        profile = userprofiles[0]
        profile.profile_pic.save('{0}_social.jpg'.format(user.username))
        profile.save()
    elif len(recruiters):
        recruiter = recruiters[0]
        recruiter.cover_pic.save('{0}_social.jpg'.format(user.username))
        recruiter.save()
    else:
        # User has neither Userprofile nor Recruiter associated with it!
        # Do something here to handle that case, or just get rid of the else
```